# How to add .java files to MonoDroid project

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android

I am trying to utilize a custom DatePicker as described [here](http://blog.codeus.net/dateslider-1-0-an-alternative-datepicker-for-android/).  But I am not sure where in my MonoDroid project to put the .java files in order to create a new instance of the DatePicker.  I've tried obj => Debug => android => src => appfolder where all of the java files for my activities are stored, but still am unable to access the DatePicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put them "anywhere"...except within the `obj` and `bin` folders (those directories tend to get removed when `Clean`ing your project...).

The important thing is that you:

1. Add the file to your project.
2. Set the **Build action** to `AndroidJavaSource`

The file can be in the toplevel of your project, or you could create a Java folder, or whatever. All that matters is that it be added to the `.csproj` and that it have the correct Build action.

Comment: How can I use the java class from C# code? What is namespace and name of this java class?

Comment: @(AndroidJavaSource) files *not* bound like in a Binding project. There is no C# binding for those types. Consequently, usage is more constrained: you can use JNI via e.g. Java.Interop.JniEnvironment to create and use instances of those types. Or, if it's e.g. an `Activity` subclass, `StartActivity(Java.Lang.Class)` can be used.

If you need a "proper" C# type, use a BInding project.